# Consistent error of Alias Name cannot match another table/alias name in FROM clause

Tags: sql, teradata

I am new to SQL and programming in general and am writing to write a data pull which would pull the monetary value for the category as well as department for each observation that we have. Yet I encounter this error. Any help is really appreciated.

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(sales.store_nbr,0) AS INT) AS "Store NUMBER", dept.acct_dept_nbr AS "Department NUMBER", dept.dept_desc AS "Department Description", SUM(sales.wkly_sales) AS "Weekly sales",SUM(sales.yrly_sales) AS "Yearly Sales"
--pull sales and quantity by store
FROM CA_WM_VM.SKU_DLY_POS sales, CA_WM_VM.DEPT_DESC dept, ca_wm_vm.item item, CA_WM_VM_SKU_YRLY_POS sales
--for a store, for a period of time
WHERE sales.item_nbr = item.item_nbr
AND item.dept_nbr = dept.acct_dept_nbr
AND sales.wm_yr_wk BETWEEN 11613 AND 11713
--group by store number, & dept number
GROUP BY sales.store_nbr, dept.acct_dept_nbr, dept.dept_desc
```

Comment: If you are new to SQL, the first thing you should do is forget about writing commas in the `FROM` clause.  Why would you want to learn archaic syntax?  `JOIN` is more powerful and more readable.

Comment: Thats true, I shall look more into it when I am able to get this right.Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and last table in the from clause have the same alias name "sales".